# Have my doubts if "may not have died " is third conditional

Tags: conditional-constructions

> Prof Saayman said the head wound would have been incapacitating but added Ms Steenkamp **may not have died** straight away.
> <sub>Source: [Sky News – *Pistorius Throws Up During 'Graphic' Evidence*](http://uk.news.yahoo.com/pistorius-court-second-week-trial-070732633.html)</sub>

I am sure that "it would have been incapacitating" is third conditional but I think "may not have died" is not third conditional.  So what is it?

Comment: The terms "1st, 2nd, 3rd conditional" do not represent any linguistic actuality. They are merely tools for teaching beginners. At your level of knowledge of English, they are no longer needed - on the contrary, they are starting to confuse you. Throw them away.

Answer (score 2):

There is not an explicit conditional here since there is no condition (*IF*) clause. Consequently, you cannot treat this as that pedagogic fiction, the  "third conditional".

There is a contextually ***im***plicit condition, but it is not supplied by the second clause here. It is clear from the account (and corroborated in other reports) that what Prof. Saayman said was that

> The wound would have been incapacitating *if Ms. Steenkamp had survived*.

The statement that “Ms. Steenkamp may not have died straight away” is cast in the present tense (perfect construction) because it represents Prof. Saayman’s present assessment of the possibility that Ms. Steenkamp’s death was immediate.

Comment: I've not been following the case in great detail, but if those were indeed his exact words then arguably OP's reported rephrasing makes more sense. With no other context, I would take *if Ms. Steenkamp had survived* to imply she could never effect a complete recovery even in the longer term. But presumably what he *meant* was that she'd have been instantly incapacitated (even if she wasn't instantly killed, which may have been the case), so she couldn't have escaped, retaliated, or taken any other remedial action.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I have not seen the exact words reported, but I agree: Prof. Saaymand did not know whether she died immediately or lingered in an incapacitated state.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: [The Guardian:]She would have lost consciousness and "the deceased probably didn't breathe more than a few times after sustaining this wound", Saayman said. "The wound to the head was incapacitating and probably almost instantly fatal."